# NSURLRequest not authenticating on wifi network outside of office

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have an app that makes an NSURLRequest to web services on our https Intranet site.  When I'm connected to our office network, it authenticates just fine and I can make these web service calls. However, if I'm on an outside network, the app can't authenticate me in order to make these calls.

I'm using an HTTP Post request. And I know the code for that is just fine because it works when I'm on the company wifi.

I've tried using WillSendRequestForAuthenticationChalllenge and canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace, and the former gets called.  I properly use the credential, but I still get a "you have been logged out" response from the web service.

I have been told that clear text authentication isn't allowed to login to our Intranet.

I've also tried using this:

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", [self username], [self password]];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
[theRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, it is "Intranet" that you are working upon. Intranet are generally local websites that can be accessed only in a particular network. 
Are you sure, this website is accessible outside your office network? The request might just be getting timed-out. Check the error which is being returned to your request

Comment: Definitely accessible outside the office network.  If I go to a web browser and try it, it asks me for my username and password and then logs me in.  The error is a "you've been logged out" message

Comment: What is the error that your NSURLRequest is getting back?